# ( Oracle VirtualBox 4 on Windows 7 64-bit ) + ( CentOS 5.6 64-bit ) = " Your CPU does not support long mode. Use a 32bit distribution "

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, centos

- VM: Oracle VirtualBox 4.0.10 r72479
- Host OS: Windows 7 64-bit
- Guest OS: CentOS 5.6 64-bit

Downloaded a ready-made image of the guest OS from [here](http://virtualboxes.org/images/centos/).

When running, CentOS tells me:

> Your CPU does not support long mode. Use a 32bit distribution.

[image: CentOS's error message]

Also mounting the original distribution's DVD doesn't work.
What's wrong? It happened me before with other OSs (in VirtualBox only) but now I actually need that.

Any way to resolve this or should I use another VM tool? Google search doesn't give much.

**Edit #1**
Some of my system's details:

> CPU Type: DualCore Intel Core 2 Duo E7300, 2666 MHz (10 x 267)
>   Motherboard Name: Asus P5KPL-CM  (2 PCI, 1 PCI-E x1, 1 PCI-E x16, 2
>   DDR2 DIMM, Audio, Video, Gigabit LAN)
> Motherboard Chipset: Intel
>   Bearlake G31
> BIOS Type:    AMI (01/26/08)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your host machine have [hardware virtualization support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization) (VT-x/AMD-V), is that support enabled in the host BIOS, and is the option for hardware assisted virtualization checked in the virtual machine configuration?

Having working VT-x/AMD-V is a [requirement](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#intro-64bitguests) for running a 64-bit guest.

Comment: Hi stephen! I've got into my BIOS in order to check if I have there anything related to virtualization but I couldn't find anyhthing. Anyway at Edit #1 you can see my system's details. Could you tell if it's a compatible one? How/Where do I check that? I'm totally lost in this area.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Nevermind, found the answer to that :/    Thank you anyway !